# org agenda: show todo entries & todo entries scheduled for today

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is there a way to make agenda show todos that have no timestamp & those that have, but are scheduled for today? 
It seems like i can do one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how you do each one separately?